# Flutter/Firebase: Trying to get Data from Firebase Collection

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from my collection on firebase, but it keeps on returning "There is No data".  The code is for my build and the link is a picture of my firebase console.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Friends'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('There Is NO DATA');
          return ListView.separated(
              separatorBuilder: (context, i) =>
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return _buildRow(snapshot.data.documents[i]);
              });
        }),
    );
  }

Widget _buildRow(DocumentSnapshot document) {
    return ListTile(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
        title: Text(
          document['name'],
        ),
        onTap:(){
          messenger = document;
          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (context) => Chat()));
        }
    );
```

Firebase Console:

[image: Firebase Console]

Comment: paste the code for - `_buildRow`

Comment: what is the issue here ? your code is working fine for me . printed Text(snapshot.data.documents[i]['name'])

Comment: Added buildRow, and my issue is its returning "there is NO DATA" because of this line so the snapshot is sayings its empty. if(!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('There Is NO DATA');